# C# extension methods example needed

Tags: c#

Please provide me and explain me extension method in C#.

like:

```
public static class MyMathExtension 
{ 
    public static int factorial(this int x) 
    { 
        if (x <= 1) return 1; 
        if (x == 2) return 2; 
        else 
            return x * factorial(x - 1); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Wrong place for such things mate !

Comment: You could find it over the internet, try google it.

Comment: Refer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: I am new in .net. on my first post you guys are saying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code:

```
public static class MyMathExtension 
{ 
    public static int factorial(this int x) 
    { 
        if (x <= 1) return 1; 
        if (x == 2) return 2; 
        else 
            return x * factorial(x - 1); 
    } 
}
```

Complete Code for My Demo

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            int x = 3; 
            Console.WriteLine(x.factorial()); 
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        } 
    } 
        public static class MyMathExtension 
        { 
            public static int factorial(this int x) 
            { 
                if (x <= 1) return 1; 
                if (x == 2) return 2; 
                else 
                    return x * factorial(x - 1); 
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: i will try this code..

Comment: even u can try this link:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension